# Why does Ubuntu keep replacing my Sources.list file during installation?

Tags: kubuntu

I am attempting to make a custom ISO based off Kubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) and I use cubic to compile it into a ISO. Every time I install it, it replaces my sources.list with the default Ubuntu one by default for no reason whatsoever. Is there a way I can permanently replace the sources.list file?

Comment: Please update the question and explain how you make the distro. Which software do you use? From my knowlege, there are two places, where the sources list comes from. 1. base.tgz, 2. apt package.

Comment: I updated the comment for more clarification, sorry about that.

Comment: Please update the question and add on which Ubuntu version you are working and for which Ubuntu version you want to create the distro. Actually cubic does not create distros, it creates ISO images (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator).

Comment: I updated the comment for more clarification, sorry about that.

Comment: As I have not used cubic yet, it would me take hours to install it and dig into the system to see at which point the problem is. I fear at the end, it works in my test environment, because you just added a config which has the effect you describe and all my time was wasted. Maybe somebody with more knowledge of cubic will show by and can solve this immediately.

Comment: The `sources.list` is not copied from the installer system. It's generated based on things like the location and mirrors selected during installation. https://askubuntu.com/a/1059993/158442

Comment: is there a way i can edit how its generated?

Answer (score 0):

This answer was adapted from [How to retain a custom `sources.list` after the customized OS has been installed?](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/issues/78#issuecomment-1179442185). This solution will work for Ubuntu Desktop 22.04, 22.10, and the 23.04 *Legacy Installer* ISO.

1. On your host machine, create a `sources.list` file with the contents you desire, and save it.
2. In [Cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic)'s [Terminal page](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Page), create a directory to store your `sources.list` file.

   ```
   mkdir /opt/apt
   cd /opt/apt
   ```
3. [Drag and drop](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Copy-Page) your `sources.list` file from step 1 onto the [Terminal page](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Page) to copy it into the current directory (`/opt/apt`).
4. Make sure the permissions are correct.

   ```
   chmod a=r,u=rw sources.list
   ls -la sources.list
   # -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jul  8 19:15 sources.list
   ```
5. Copy the new `sources.list` file to `/etc/apt` so you can continue customizing your OS.

   ```
   cp /opt/apt/sources.list /etc/apt
   ```
6. Continue customizing your OS.

   ```
   apt update
   ```

   Make additional changes, as desired.
7. Use [preseeding](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation) to update the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file after it is overwritten by [Ubiquity](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ubiquity.8.html).

   On Cubic's [Options page](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Options-Page), on the [Preseed tab](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Options-Page#preseed-tab), add the following at the end of the `ubuntu.seed` file:

   ```
   ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
       in-target bash -c 'cp /opt/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/';
   ```

   This will copy the correct `sources.list` file from `/opt/apt/` to `/etc/apt/` after successful installation of your customized OS.
8. Generate your customized ISO and test.