# What page does Ubuntu use to validate the geolocation of public IPs?

Tags: networking

Good morning,
I hope you are well.
I would like to ask you a question? We recently acquired a public segment in Colombia, but when we download ubuntu they begin to be downloaded from servers in Costa Rica..... Could you tell me which page ubuntu uses to validate the geolocation of the ips do you publish?

Comment: Related: [How is the sources.list file generated on installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059975/how-is-the-sources-list-file-generated-on-installation)

Comment: Please check here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily get a mirror close to you. I get a UK mirror, from Norway. There's no particular problem with that.